# Any way to avoid using `grep -v`

Tags: linux, unix, grep

When performing a grep filtering across pipes, as in the following example,

```
$ ps -ef | grep 24604 
username   18660 24604  0 16:38 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ef
username   18661 24604  0 16:38 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 24604
username   24604 23548  0 Aug13 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

the grep command itself is part of the results, and usually - I filter it out with another `grep -v,` viz.:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 24604 | grep -v grep
username   20375 24604  0 16:40 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ef
username   24604 23548  0 Aug13 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

Is there a `grep` argument which will filter out the grep string?
(Or any other trick to avoid the `grep -v`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically handled by putting brackets around the first character:

```
$ ps auxw | grep [c]ron
root      5710  0.0  0.0  10640  1800 ?        Ss   14:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
$
```

This works because `cron` no longer appears in `grep`s command line ([c]ron does). A more modern approach is to use the `pgrep` command if available.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`pgrep -l 24604`

It really depends on the usage, but `pgrep` is usually more suited for automation which is probably what you're trying to do.